# How can I sort the xml nodes in a file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, io

I have a XML file in which I want to sort the `Object` nodes alphabetically and write them back to the file. The raw file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package>
  <Objects>
    <Object Type="Package">moB</Object>
    <Object Type="Package">moA</Object>
    <Object Type="Package">moC</Object>
  </Objects>
</Package>
```

The expected output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package>
  <Objects>
    <Object Type="Package">moA</Object>
    <Object Type="Package">moB</Object>
    <Object Type="Package">moC</Object>
  </Objects>
</Package>
```

I want to solve this with LINQ, unfortunately I can't get the query to read the `Object` nodes as a collection for further processing.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(inputFile);
var orderedList = xdoc.Root.Element("Objects");
```

Comment: Currently you're fetching the single `Objects` node, rather than the several `Object` nodes.  Try instead `xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Package/Objects/Object");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I want to solve this with LINQ, unfortunately I can't get the query to read the `Object` nodes as a collection for further processing.*

You are only reading the root node `Objects`, this will give an `XElement` object and not a collection, you need to read all the inner `Object` nodes:

```
var objectList = xdoc.Root.Element("Objects").Elements("Object");
```

The result is an `IEnumerable<XElement>` which you can manipulate with LINQ.

> *I want to sort the `Object` nodes alphabetically and write them back to the file.*

When you have the collection of `Object` you can sort it by the inner text:

```
var orderedList = objectList.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
```

And replace the old `Object` nodes by the ordered ones:

```
xdoc.Root.Element("Objects").ReplaceNodes(orderedList);
```

After that it's just a matter of saving this back to the file:

```
xdoc.Save(inputFile); // will replace the content
```

If you want to keep the original just save this to a different file:

```
xdoc.Save("someOtherFile.xml");
```

Here you have a run of the described program, showing the file before and after:

[image]

### Side note:

Be aware that you have non-printable characters in the posted xml content that will break your program:

[image]

Comment: var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Test.xml");
var objectList = xdoc.Root.Element("Objects").Elements("Object");  I have the following error.. System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in this line..

Comment: @BlackDevOps, you must have some typo in the node names, either in the program, or the file itself I posted a gif with the execution in my answer. Be aware of non printable characters ithat sometimes go in copy/pastes, you have those int the sample file you show.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to illustrate this for me with an example. Your solution helped me a lot to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this line, in order to select the Objects elements and order them :

```
var orderedList = xdoc.Root.Element("Objects")
                      .Elements("Object")
                      .OrderBy(e => e.Value);
```

Then you should create a new xElement to hold the sorted object elements and replace the original with the sorted version, and just save the modified doc!

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it's clear how to navigate to the xml-nodes. But I have the following error.. System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) has returned zero. The root object is ok.